# Form field custom attribute

Tags: kentico

I am building a form by using the Kentico Form Application.

I need to add in other attributes into the input fields. But the input field seems like not editable. I am editing it in the Layout tab, and view in html source

```
<div class="form-group">$$label:Message$$* $$input:Message$$
  <p class="charCount"><span>0</span>/400</p>
</div>
```

It suppose to be look like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Cover message*</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" maxlength="400" required></textarea>
    <p class="charCount"><span>0</span>/400</p>
</div>
```

But how can I make it by using the Kentico Form Application?

Answer (score 3):

CSS classes (`class`) and validation rules (`maxlength`) can be added and modified in Forms->Edit form->Fields->Select field. You can also wrap the fields in custom HTML code by setting the HTML envelope.

Regarding identifiers (`id`,`name`), you can't control them unless you create a [custom form control](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-form-controls/example-developing-custom-form-controls).

Comment: You can target specific controls @SoYuje by looking at the surrounding `<div>` for the form controls.  BUT this only works if you use the default layout.  Any custom layout's you'd have to wrap your own IDs around the controls.